# Repeating hAxis labels when slanting text - Google Charts

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

We are using Google Charts within an MVC project.

We have managed to get the chart implemented however we are having a slight issue.

Whenever we slant the text 90 degrees the hAxis labels are repeating (see below).
[image]

We would like the text to be slanted at 90 degree but only have the label appear once on the hAxis (see below).

[image]

Things we've tried (that had no effect on the chart):

Setting the hAxis grid lines :

```
 hAxis: {
           slantedText: true,
           slantedTextAngle: 90,
           gridlines: {count: 7}
        },
```

Setting the hAxis minor grid lines:

```
hAxis: {
          slantedText: true,
          slantedTextAngle: 90,
          minorGridlines: { count: 5 }
       },
```

Is there a way we can achieve the desired result for the hAxis labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using a [continuous axis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous),
provide your own `ticks` to ensure no repeats...

`ticks` takes an array of values of the same data type as the axis

each tick can be a raw value, such as a date --> `new Date(2017, 3, 2)`

or you can use object notation,
to provide both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

```
{v: new Date(2017, 3, 2), f: '2017'}
```

these can be built dynamically, using data table method --> `getColumnRange`
which returns an object with the `min` & `max` values for the column

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [{type: 'date'}, {type: 'number'}, {type: 'number'}],
      [new Date(2008, 2, 5), 10, 2],
      [new Date(2008, 6, 6), 25, 4],
      [new Date(2008, 10, 8), 30, 6],
      [new Date(2009, 3, 2), 50, 7],
      [new Date(2009, 8, 12), 60, 8],
      [new Date(2009, 11, 20), 62, 9],
      [new Date(2010, 2, 5), 64, 10],
      [new Date(2010, 6, 6), 70, 10],
      [new Date(2010, 10, 8), 71, 10],
      [new Date(2011, 3, 2), 100, 12],
      [new Date(2012, 8, 12), 125, 12],
      [new Date(2012, 11, 20), 160, 12],
      [new Date(2013, 10, 8), 71, 10],
      [new Date(2014, 3, 2), 100, 12],
      [new Date(2015, 8, 12), 125, 12],
      [new Date(2016, 9, 20), 160, 12],
      [new Date(2016, 10, 8), 71, 10],
      [new Date(2017, 3, 2), 100, 12],
      [new Date(2017, 5, 12), 125, 12],
      [new Date(2017, 6, 20), 160, 12]
    ]);

    var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
    var oneYear = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
    var ticksAxisH = [];
    for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneYear) {
      var tick = new Date(i);
      ticksAxisH.push({
        v: tick,
        f: tick.getFullYear().toString()
      });
    }

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        ticks: ticksAxisH
      },
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

the `ticks` option is only supported by a continuous axis (date, number, etc...)
and is unavailable for a discrete axis (string)

use a data view to convert the first column to a number...

```
// convert first column to number
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return parseInt(dt.getValue(row, 0));
  },
  label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
  type: 'number'
}, 1, 2]);
```

then use data table / view method --> `getDistinctValues(colIndex)`
this will return an array of the distinct values in the column,
which can be used for the `ticks`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"type": "string" ,"id": "Data" ,"label": "Label" },
        {"type": "number" ,"id": "Performance" ,"label": "Performance" },
        {"type": "number" ,"id": "Index" ,"label": "Index" }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0}, {"v": "0"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0.07103609}, {"v": "0.0052939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0.12668605420031}, {"v": "0.0152939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2009"}, {"v": 0.27103609}, {"v": "0.0252939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2009"}, {"v": 0.32668605420031}, {"v": "0.0352939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2010"}, {"v": 0.37103609}, {"v": "0.0452939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2010"}, {"v": 0.42668605420031}, {"v": "0.0552939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2011"}, {"v": 0.47103609}, {"v": "0.0652939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2011"}, {"v": 0.52668605420031}, {"v": "0.0752939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2012"}, {"v": 0.57103609}, {"v": "0.0852939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2012"}, {"v": 0.62668605420031}, {"v": "0.0952939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2013"}, {"v": 0.67103609}, {"v": "0.1052939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2013"}, {"v": 0.72668605420031}, {"v": "0.2152939"}]}
      ]
    });

    // convert first column to number
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([{
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return parseInt(dt.getValue(row, 0));
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      type: 'number'
    }, 1, 2]);

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        format: '0',
        ticks: view.getDistinctValues(0)
      },
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));
    chart.draw(view, options);  // <-- use view to draw chart
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

another option would be to leave the axis as discrete (string),
and simply remove the duplicate labels from the data

this can also be accomplished using a data view...

```
// remove duplicates from first column
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var xValue = dt.getValue(row, 0);
    if ((row > 0) && (xValue === dt.getValue(row - 1, 0))) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return xValue;
    }
  },
  label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
  type: 'string'
}, 1, 2]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"type": "string" ,"id": "Data" ,"label": "Label" },
        {"type": "number" ,"id": "Performance" ,"label": "Performance" },
        {"type": "number" ,"id": "Index" ,"label": "Index" }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0}, {"v": "0"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0.07103609}, {"v": "0.0052939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0.12668605420031}, {"v": "0.0152939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2009"}, {"v": 0.27103609}, {"v": "0.0252939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2009"}, {"v": 0.32668605420031}, {"v": "0.0352939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2010"}, {"v": 0.37103609}, {"v": "0.0452939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2010"}, {"v": 0.42668605420031}, {"v": "0.0552939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2011"}, {"v": 0.47103609}, {"v": "0.0652939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2011"}, {"v": 0.52668605420031}, {"v": "0.0752939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2012"}, {"v": 0.57103609}, {"v": "0.0852939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2012"}, {"v": 0.62668605420031}, {"v": "0.0952939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2013"}, {"v": 0.67103609}, {"v": "0.1052939"}]},
        {"c" : [{"v": "2013"}, {"v": 0.72668605420031}, {"v": "0.2152939"}]}
      ]
    });

    // remove duplicates from first column
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([{
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        var xValue = dt.getValue(row, 0);
        if ((row > 0) && (xValue === dt.getValue(row - 1, 0))) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return xValue;
        }
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      type: 'string'
    }, 1, 2]);

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 12,
        left: 24,
        bottom: 48,
        right: 4
      },
      hAxis: {
        maxAlternation: 1
      },
      height: '100%',
      legend: 'none',
      width: '100%'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));
    chart.draw(view, options);
    $(window).resize(function() {
      chart.draw(view, options);
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply WhiteHat, I've tried to integrate your solution with our own and I am getting the following error:

TypeError: dateRange.min.getTime is not a function

Now I assume I am getting this error because we are using String as the column type and not DateTime (See data table).

Is there way we can get it to work with string?

Comment: Hopefully this is what you was after:
{"cols": [{"type": "string" ,"id": "Data" ,"label": "Label" }, {"type": "number" ,"id": "Performance" ,"label": "Performance" }, {"type": "number" ,"id": "Index" ,"label": "Index" }], "rows" : [{"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0}, {"v": "0"}]}, {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0.07103609}, {"v": "0.0052939"}]}, {"c" : [{"v": "2008"}, {"v": 0.12668605420031}

Comment: Thank you for the edit WhiteHat! it worked! however the line chart is now not displaying correctly. See this link http://imgur.com/a/eE10V

Comment: strange, maybe try __EDIT 2__ above...?

Comment: Thank you for all your help thus WhiteHat its greatly appreciated.
I copy and pasted Edit 2 and this was the outcome http://imgur.com/hyjBPex

As you can see... the data is displaying correctly but now the hAxis is messed up (WE CANT WIN! Haha)

Comment: i noticed that here as well, it seems if you use `maxAlternation: 1`, then sometimes labels are missing, without it, they appear on separate lines, i'll let you know if i come up with something else -- probably wait until later when i can access the full data table...

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat! Do you know of somewhere you can access that will allow me to copy over the data table?

Answer (score 0):

VICTORY!

So I finally got it working. WhiteHat you're an absolute genius! Thank you!  EDIT 2 did the trick, however I added an extra property to the hAxis for it to display all labels (see below).

```
showTextEvery:1
```

Below is the full implementation for anyone else having this issue.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(perfData)));

                                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                                view.setColumns([{
                                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                                        var xValue = dt.getValue(row, 0);
                                        if ((row > 0) && (xValue === dt.getValue(row-1, 0))) {
                                            return null;
                                        } else {
                                            return xValue;
                                        }
                                    },
                                    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
                                    type: 'string'
                                }, 1, 2]);

                                var options = {
                                    chartArea : { left: 40, top:10},
                                    width:450,
                                    height: 300,

                                    hAxis: {
                                        slantedText: true,
                                        slantedTextAngle: 90,
                                        showTextEvery:1
                                    },

                                    legend:{position:'bottom'},
                                    vAxis: {
                                        format: '#%',
                                        gridlines: {count: 7}
                                    }
                                };
                                var chart_div = document.getElementById('returnsChart');
                                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chart_div);

                                chart.draw(view, options);
                                $(window).resize(function () {
                                    chart.draw(view, options);
                                });
```

below is the final image:

[image]